# Drawing an almost straight line

Tags: python, drawing, geometry, pixel

I got these arrays representing squared paper, or maybe pixels if you like. For consistency in this thread, let "1" represent a black cell, "0" represent a white cell.

Now, I want to draw a (black) straight line from point A to point B. I can't just use a vanilla http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm, because I need to blacken every cell that would be hit if it were a sheet of squared paper and you drew a line from the center of square A to the center of square B.

So these should work out as follows:

```
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
|A| | |    |█| | |
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | | |    |█|█| |
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | | | →  | |█|█|
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | |B|    | | |█|
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+

+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
|A| | |    |█| | |
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | | | →  | |█| |
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | |B|    | | |█|
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+

+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
|A| | | →  |█|█| |
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | |B|    | |█|█|
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
```

Feel free to imagine these sketches to be more square-like, or to actually sketch that on a sheet of squared paper! It might clear things up.

And like always, feel free to post anything that might help. Thanks!

---

(A) Solution

Also using this example. And using the indices as they're used by my framework, so it looks a little different than the one in the answers.

```
 X 0 1 2      X 0 1 2
Y +—+—+—+ →  Y +—+—+—+
0 |A| | | →  0 |█| | |
  +—+—+—+ →    +—+—+—+
1 | | | | →  1 |█|█| |
  +—+—+—+ →    +—+—+—+
2 | | | | →  2 | |█|█|
  +—+—+—+ →    +—+—+—+
3 | | |B| →  3 | | |█|
  +—+—+—+ →    +—+—+—+
```

A being (0,0) =: (a1,a2), B being (2,3) =: (b1,b2), so the expected set of points is {(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (2,3)}

First, we formalize the straight which would be drawn on actual paper.

```
Therefore first define constant m which holds our slope:

    (b2 - a2)
m = —————————
    (b1 - a1)

For arbitrary (A, B), the straight is now defined by:
g: y = (x - a1) · m + a2

and inverted:
ǵ: x = (y - a2) / m + a1

Note that for m = 0, the whole thing does fail. But a straight-to-the-right line does not only sound like a straightforward thing.
```

in this example, the straights are

```
m = 3/2
g: y = x * 3/2
ǵ: x = y * 2/3
```

We'll feed these functions with the "line values" (exactly between 2 integers x and x+1, widely known as "x and a halve") within our bounding box. So first we'll go between a1 and b1 (feed g), then between a2 and b2 (feed ǵ):

```
g(0.5) = 1/2 * 3/2 = 0.75 // 1 < g(0.5) + 0.5 < 2
g(1.5) = 3/2 * 3/2 = 2.25 // 2 < g(1.5) + 0.5 < 3

ǵ(0.5) = 1/2 * 2/3 = 0.33 // 0 < ǵ(0.5) + 0.5 < 1
ǵ(1.5) = 3/2 * 2/3 = 1    // 1 < ǵ(1.5) + 0.5 < 2
ǵ(2.5) = 5/2 * 2/3 = 1.66 // 2 < ǵ(2.5) + 0.5 < 3
```

1. First means the straight crosses the first vertical line above (shown as "below") the first horizontal line. Points to get black: (0,1), (1,1).
2. Second means the straight crosses the second vertical line above the second horizontal line. Points to get black: (1,2), (2,2).
3. Third means the straight crosses the first horizontal line after (shown as "right of") the 0th vertical line. Points to get black: (0,0), (0,1).
4. Fourth means the straight crosses the second horizontal line after the first vertical line. Points to get black: (1,1), (1,2).
5. Fifth means the straight crosses the third horizontal line after the second vertical line. Points to get black: (2,2), (2,3).

All points: {(0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (0,0), **(0,1)**, **(1,1)**, **(1,2)**, **(2,2)**, (2,3)}

Without **duplicates**: {(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (2,3)} (which is exactly as expected)

- So for a line that crosses the y'th vertical line above the x'th horizontal one, we paint (x-1,y) and (x,y) black.
- While for a line that crosses the x'th horizontal line after the y'th vertical one, we paint (x,y-1) and (x,y).
- (never true here) And for a line that crosses the x'th horizontal *right on* the y'th vertical one, we paint for m > 0 (x-1,y-1) and (x,y). If m < 0, that'd make for (x-1,y) and (x,y-1)

Feels about right, that's my idea.

Any thoughts? Please comment!

~ LDer ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that we're working with this example:

```
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
|A| | |    |█| | |
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | | |    |█|█| |
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | | | →  | |█|█|
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
| | |B|    | | |█|
+—+—+—+    +—+—+—+
```

It's a rectangle `3x4`.

We need to define two functions:
`y(x) = 4 * (1 - x/3)`
`x(y) = 3 * (1 - y/4)`.

Now let's pass to them all integer `x` and `y` inside our rectangle.
On each step we are painting black pixel with coordinates
`[x; ceil(y(x)) - 1]` and `[ceil(x(y)) - 1; y - 1]`:

```
y(0) == 4      # paint 0;3
y(1) == 2.(6)  # paint 1;2
y(2) == 1.(3)  # paint 2;1

x(0) == 3      # paint 2;-1 (-1 is not a valid pixel coordinate, 
               # so we may just throw away this, as there are no pixels below y=0)
x(1) == 2.25   # paint 2;0
x(2) == 1.5    # paint 1;1
x(3) == 0.75   # paint 0;2
```

Both `x(y)` and `y(x)` functions are giving you second coordinate of a point on the diagonal, and when we're passing integer values to them, we're finding intersections of our diagonal with the grid.
The `y`-function would give us all pixels that are right to every vertical line and the `x`-function - that are below every horizontal (that's why `y - 1`). The only issue will be with corner intersections, it can be solved by one more conditional.

Comment: How did you get from [ceil(x(1)) - 1; 1] to [2; 0]? I like the solution, and now have my own directly-applicable idea roughly based upon that :) Hope it works out well. Additionally, It'd be awesome if you clarified how you made up your numbers...

Comment: So [ceil(x(2)) - 1; 2] to [1; 1] (should be [1; 2]) is that same mysterious transition, as well as [ceil(x(3)) - 1; 3] to [0; 2] (should be [0; 3]), leaving me with only [ (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0) ] as distinct values? Wait a minute, that's bresenham'd! D:

Comment: @LDericher hmm, you're right, there's something wrong. I'll try to reproduce my thoughts to myself once more just now.

Comment: @LDericher yeah, I got it. Wait a couple of minutes, I'll try to paint it somewhere.

Comment: I got it too, it's about evaluating your functions at the .5's steps (the "lines") and then deciding which 2 squares are exactly left/right (resp. above/below) of the intersection point...

Comment: @LDericher that's first option. The second is to evaluate it over   the integers and use `[ceil(x(y)) - 1; y - 1]` coordinate. The `y`-function would give us all pixels that are right to every vertical line and `x`-function - that are below every horizontal (that's why `y - 1`). The only issue will be with corner intersections, it can be solved by one more conditional.

Comment: Updated the question. Did you mean that? And does that sound right?

Comment: @LDericher Sounds good. I'm far from a PC right now, later I'll try one idea. But to say about exact integer crosses I think we have no need to paint upper pixel. It's already painted by `y` function. We just need to go downright `[x-1, y-1]` in both functions and paint it. I think that would work just as we want it to.

Answer (score 1):

**Initialisation**
Give the vertices of your "squares" coordinates `(x,y)`. For each square, *v1* is top left, *v2* top right, *v3* bottom right and *v4* bottom left. Calculate the equation of your line `y = a*x + b`.

**Algorithm**

```
For each square do
    for each vertex of the square do
        calculate valueOfVertex = y - a*x - b
    if two valueOfVertex have an opposite sign
    then cellColor == 1
    else cellcolor == 0
```

The output should be what you expect. The only problem maybe if one `valueOfVertex = 0` and all the others are stricly positive or negative. But it's easy to handle.

**Explanation** If the line crosses the square (or pixel), you can find two vertice which aren't on the same side of the line. So one lies in the positive half plane, the other in the negative half plane.

**Improvement** Some simple tricks will prevent you from testing every square of the bounding box. If you find a square that is entirely in a half plane, you can discard some squares. In your examples, if the square tested is above the line, you can discard all the squares that are above and to the right.

Comment: I'd like something more efficient, what doesn't force me to look at each vertex but rather (promises to) return all the squares that are to be painted. If my current idea doesn't do well, I might try this one instead...

Comment: Another possibility to be more efficient : start from A (which you know is black) and evaluate the neighbor squares. If the neighbor square is black, add its neighbors to the queue.
Given the vertice of a square, you can also induce which neighbor square can be black or white. A way to improve the algorithm.

Comment: Of course, the order in which squares are tested makes a difference; but I want to improve the other solution first. No offense :)